# Problema na hora do scanf() de uma string

Tags: c, string, scanf

Eu queria uma ajuda na solução do problema de uma *string*, pois quando se lê o programa automaticamente da como opção inválida qualquer opção, assim não se valendo da opção que eu escolhi. No `if` já tentei com `&&` ao invés de `||` e também não deu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char sexo[2];

 printf("---Sexo---\n");
 printf("1 - Masculino\n");
 printf("2 - Feminino\n");
 setbuf(stdin, NULL);
 fgets(sexo,2,stdin);
 if(sexo[2]!='1' || sexo[2]!='2')
 {
   printf("\nOpção Inválida\n");
   system("PAUSE");
   sexo[2]=0;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Não faz sentido ler desta forma, peça um inteiro e seja feliz. Entenda que estes mecanismos padrões de console de C, especialmente leitura, existem só pra fazer coisas muito básicas e em códigos reais as pessoas usam mecanismos próprios ou de bibliotecas que executam isto de forma mais adequada. O objetivo do uso deles é só pra dar sustentação para exercícios e experimentos, então os use de forma mais simples que puder evitando essas dificuldades.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("---Sexo---\n");
    printf("1 - Masculino\n");
    printf("2 - Feminino\n");
    int sexo;
    scanf("%d", &sexo);
    if (sexo != 1 && sexo != 2) printf("\nOpção Inválida\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OREcgx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ScanfOption). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfOption.c).

Comment: O programa que estou fazendo terá que comparar uma variavel sexo a outra sexo2, se eu usar como valor inteiro ao invés de string, e na hora de comparar irá funcionar usando If ?

Comment: Sim, de forma até melhor. Se for insistir no `char` dá para fazer também, mas dá trabalho fazer certo, tem que começar se preocupar com as dificuldades de C de lidar com este tipo de entrada de dados, é complicação à toa pra exercício.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, há alguns erros no seu código. Atribui 1 ou 2 à variável sexo, logo tem de ser do tipo int e não char. Char é para caracteres, a menos que use uma função que converta de char para int. Depois no if, visto que sexo é do tipo int não precisa das ' '.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int sexo;

 printf("---Sexo---\n");
 printf("1 - Masculino\n");
 printf("2 - Feminino\n");
 scanf("%d",&sexo);
 if(sexo!=1 && sexo!=2)
 {
   printf("\nOpção Inválida\n");
   system("PAUSE");
 }
 return 0;
}
```